# Next.js render pages issue with getInitProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am implementing protecting routes in Next.js, on each page I added:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      protected: true,
    },
  };
}
```

After included getStaticProps on each page, I started getting the next error in _document.jsx getInitProps:

[image]

This is the exact place where error happens:

```
    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
       enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
     });
```

This is **_document.jsx file**

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
   const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
   const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

   try {
     ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
       enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
     });

     const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
     return {
       ...initialProps,
       styles: (
         <>
           {initialProps.styles}
           {sheet.getStyleElement()}
         </>
       ),
     };
   } finally {
     sheet.seal();
   }
}
```

Any idea what is the error? I am trying to understand where is a problem

Comment: You are trying to render something thats is undefined. Maybe you got some error on your try block. Put a catch on your try block and try to see wich error are you getting. Keep in mind that getStaticProps always run on the serverSide, things that are avaible in the client wont be there.

Comment: Can you show the full code of the component where you have `getStaticProps`? The issue is most likely not in your `_document`, one of the React components isn't getting exported/imported properly.